# Find Match Result with PHP or PERL

Tags: php, perl

I have 2 files (large size)

- name1.txt
- name2.txt

**name1.txt :**

```
smooth - temper
left - corner
etc.
```

**name 2.txt :**

```
corner = hard
temper = small
etc.
```

How can I find match from `name1.txt` in `name2.txt`, than place it within `name3.txt`

**output name3.txt :**

```
smooth - temper = small
left - corner = hard
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: have tried reguler open with perl like : open(FILES, $tar) or print("Cannot Locate : $tar\n"); 
my @lists=<FILES>; 
close(FILES); 
foreach $list(@lists){ 
$list=~s/^\s+//; 
$list=~s/\s+$//; 
{
if($list=~/(.*):(.*)/g){
     my $name1 = $1;
     my $name2= $2; ... but have no clue how to open the second file..read it 1 by 1 till got the match...it keep read 1 result from file 1..sorry i'm new with program stuff

Comment: You should probably edit your question to include that code so that it looks like you made an effort to solve this problem yourself. Also, hashes.

Comment: What do you mean  by large size? Be specific?

Comment: I meant size of files?

Comment: there are only 2 files with large size

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how well the following will perform with large files - the test files were exactly as the example but this does return the desired result so long as I interpreted the pattern correctly.

```
        $names_1=__DIR__.'\names1.txt';
        $names_2=__DIR__.'\names2.txt';
        /* Read each source file into an array */
        $lines_1=file( $names_1, FILE_TEXT | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
        $lines_2=file( $names_2, FILE_TEXT | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );

        /* placeholders */
        $arr_1=array();
        $arr_2=array();
        $arr_3=array();
        $arr_4=array();

        /* Populate $arr_1 using value as key */
        foreach( $lines_1 as $index => $line ){
            list( $w1,$w2 )=explode('-', str_replace( ' ', '', $line ) );
            $arr_1[ $w2 ]=$w1;
        }

        /* populate arr_2 */
        foreach( $lines_2 as $index => $line ){
            list( $w1,$w2 )=explode('=', str_replace( ' ', '', $line ) );
            $arr_2[ $w1 ]=$w2;
        }

        /* Find where there are common keys between the two arrays */
        $arr_3=array_intersect_key( $arr_1, $arr_2 );

        /* populate output array in format expected */
        foreach( $arr_3 as $i => $v ){
            $arr_4[]=$arr_1[ $i ]. ' - '. $i .' = '.$arr_2[ $i ];
        }

        /* show results */
        echo '<pre>',print_r($arr_4,true),'</pre>';
```